# Не правильно работает кнопка "Назад" в браузере

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите пожалуйста, с решением js задачи:

Такая ситуация, есть 3 файла:

1. index.html
   В нем есть ссылка
   `<a href="loading.html">На витрину</a>`
2. loading.html
   В нем есть перенаправление с паузой в файл offers.html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = "offers.html";
            }, 3000);
    </script>
```

3. offers.html
   html страница, с рандомно генерируемым контентом (но это не особо важно).

Вопрос - после клика на ссылку "На витрину" в файле index.html, происходит загрузка страницы loading.html в котором происходит перенаправление на страницу  offers.html через 3 секунды. Но находясь на странице offers.html, жму в браузере (Chrome) на кнопку "назад", ожидаю что откроется страница loading.html (пройдет 3 сек и опять произойдет перенаправление на offers.html), но открывается страница index.html.

Почему? И как мне сделать чтоб при клике на браузерную кнопку "назад" открывалась страница loading.html ?

Answer (score -2):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout(function() {
                history.pushState({},0,"loading.html");
                window.location.href = "offers.html";
            }, 3000);
    </script>
```